# Understanding how to turn ._forEach into _.map

Tags: javascript, lodash, ecmascript-5

I'm working on a project with lodash v3. I have eslint-plugin-loadash setup to use the v3 recommendations.

Looking at the code below it recommends turning it from `_.forEach` into `_.map`. `inventory.minons()` is an array of objects.

```js
      var playerArmies = [setupPlayer];
      _.forEach(inventory.minions(), function () {
        playerArmies.push(setupSubCommander);
      });
```

Having looked over the documentation for `_.map` I couldn't figure out how I'd change what I have into what it suggests. I'm less worried about whether it's the right thing to do at this point (I'm a slave to the linter due to my lack of understanding) and more just trying to expand my knowledge in the hope it will help me understand future documentation.

Comment: Where does `setupSubCommander` come from?

Comment: You seem to be looking for `[setupPlayer].concat(_.repeat(setupSubCommander, inventory.minions().length))`

Comment: @Bergi it's the name of a function used elsewhere. Same for `setupPlayer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an initial value in the array, `_.map` won't keep that item.
You'll have to use `.unshift` to add the item `setupPlayer` to the start of the array.

```
var playerArmies = _.map(inventory.minions(), function () {
  return setupSubCommander;
});
playerArmies.unshift(setupPlayer); // adds item to the front of the array.
```

Comment: @Quitch no, javascript does not have operating overloading

Comment: Ah, caught my ninja deletion :D

Comment: @Quitch to use the values you have to have a new value.